# Is there a formula for determining the number of houses or households in a given area?

Tags: statistics

I was thinking along the lines of population density but applied to houses or households, but is there an actual formula for this?

EDIT:

For the context of this question, I'm trying to create an estimate on how many household(or preferably houses) are affected during a flood. I can get the `total affected area` of the flood, the `total number of household` in a barangay(smallest administrative division in the Philippines) along with its `total population`. So now I'm wondering if the formula for population density can also be applied to households, but I'm curious as to if there is an already established formula out there.

Comment: Welcome to Math SX. It is easier to answer your question if you [add some context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960): What country/region are you in? What exactly do you want to calculate? What do you already know about the region that you are in?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch For now I've edited my question and included a context. If it is still lacking, then please do tell.